# Azure C# v2 Function: Data not being inserted to Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure

I am writing a C# Azure v2 timer function that copies ten rows from one table (`OneAuthZRoleAssignments`) and inserts them into another table (`OneAuthZPreviousRoleAssignments`). My function works in reading from the `OneAuthZRoleAssignments` table (the print statements show the correct values)... however, it fails to insert the rows read into the `OneAuthZPreviousRoleAssignments` (note: the `accountName` and `accountKey` variables are defined, I have just omitted their actual values for security purposes of course). Below is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Buffers.Text;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace AccessChangeMonitoring
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        // Authenticate access into the database's Azure Table Storage
        static StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        static CloudStorageAccount account = new CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps: true);

        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        // Function that reads a small portion of the role assignments table (OneAuthZRoleAssignments) every 
        // configurable number of times
        public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%TimerTriggerPeriod%")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            // Retrieve the role assignments table
            CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
            // Current role assignments
            CloudTable roleAssignmentsTable = client.GetTableReference("OneAuthZRoleAssignments"); 
            // LKG (Last Known Good) role assignments
            CloudTable previousRoleAssignmentsTable = client.GetTableReference("OneAuthZPreviousRoleAssignments");

            // Test out retrieving a small portion from the role assignments table (10 rows)
            var tablePortion = new List<RoleAssignment>(); // Stores the query of role assignment
            TableContinuationToken token = null; // Allows our query to iterate to the next role row

            // Define our query (in this case, set the number of rows we want to retrieve at 10)
            TableQuery<RoleAssignment> tableQuery = new TableQuery<RoleAssignment>();
            tableQuery.Take(10);

            // Retrieve the rows from Azure Table Storage
            var queryResult = await roleAssignmentsTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(tableQuery, token);
            tablePortion.AddRange(queryResult.Results);

            // Copy the rows to the LKG (Last Known Good) table
            CopyRows(tablePortion, previousRoleAssignmentsTable);
        }

        [FunctionName("CopyRows")]
        // Copies a list of rows to another table 
        public static void CopyRows(List<RoleAssignment> queriedRows, CloudTable destinationTable)
        {
            // Iterate through all of the rows
            foreach (RoleAssignment row in queriedRows)
            {
                // Define the insertion operation
                TableOperation insert = TableOperation.Insert(row);
                // Execute the insertion operation
                destinationTable.ExecuteAsync(insert);

                // OUTPUTS THE CORRECT VALUES
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("Row: {0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}\n{8}\n{9}\n{10}\n{11}\n{12}" +
                    "\n{13}\n{14}\n{15}\n{16}\n{17}", row.PartitionKey, row.RowKey, row.Timestamp,
                    row.AppId, row.ApplicationName, row.AssignedAlias, row.AssignedName, row.AssignedUPN, row.Condition,
                    row.Id, row.IsBuiltIn, row.PrincipalId, row.RoleDefinitionId, row.RoleDefintionName, row.Scope, row.UpdatedBy,
                    row.UpdatedByAlias, row.UpdatedByName
                    );
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for reference, this is the entity class `RoleAssignment` which represents a row in the table:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace AccessChangeMonitoring
{
    // RoleAssignment represents a row in the Azure Table Storage OneAuthZRoleAssignments
    public class RoleAssignment:TableEntity
    {
        // Constructors
        public RoleAssignment()
        {
        }

        public RoleAssignment(string PartitionKey, string RowKey, DateTime Timestamp, Guid AppId, string ApplicationName,
            string AssignedAlias, string AssignedName, string AssignedUPN, string Condition,
            string Id, bool IsBuiltIn, string PrincipalId, string RoleDefinitionId, string RoleDefintionName,
            string Scope, string UpdatedBy, string UpdatedByAlias, string UpdatedByName)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = PartitionKey;
            this.RowKey = RowKey;
            this.TimeStamp = Timestamp;
            this.AppId = AppId;
            this.ApplicationName = ApplicationName;
            this.AssignedAlias = AssignedAlias;
            this.AssignedName = AssignedName;
            this.AssignedUPN = AssignedUPN;
            this.Condition = Condition;
            this.Id = Id;
            this.IsBuiltIn = IsBuiltIn;
            this.PrincipalId = PrincipalId;
            this.RoleDefinitionId = RoleDefinitionId;
            this.RoleDefintionName = RoleDefintionName;
            this.Scope = Scope;
            this.UpdatedBy = UpdatedBy;
            this.UpdatedByAlias = UpdatedByAlias;
            this.UpdatedByName = UpdatedByName;
        }

        // The row properties
        public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
        public Guid AppId { get; set; }
        public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
        public string AssignedAlias { get; set; }
        public string AssignedName { get; set; }
        public string AssignedUPN { get; set; }
        public string Condition { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public Boolean IsBuiltIn { get; set; }
        public string PrincipalId { get; set; }
        public string RoleDefinitionId { get; set; }
        public string RoleDefintionName { get; set; }
        public string Scope { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedByAlias { get; set; }
        public string UpdatedByName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Below is the `OneAuthZRoleAssignments` table:
[image]

This seems strange, considering that I can read the data from the `OneAuthZRoleAssignments` table and both the table that I am reading from (`OneAuthZRoleAssignments`) and the table that I am writing from (`OneAuthZPreviousRoleAssignments`) are in the same storage account:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an exception happening in `destinationTable.ExecuteAsync(insert);` which you are not seeing because you are missing `await`. See how these changes to your code change the result:

```cs
            // Copy the rows to the LKG (Last Known Good) table
            CopyRows(tablePortion, previousRoleAssignmentsTable);
        }

        public static void CopyRows(List<RoleAssignment> queriedRows, CloudTable destinationTable)
        {
//...
                destinationTable.ExecuteAsync(insert);
```

Change that to:

```cs
            // Copy the rows to the LKG (Last Known Good) table
            await CopyRows(tablePortion, previousRoleAssignmentsTable);
        }

        public static async Task CopyRows(List<RoleAssignment> queriedRows, CloudTable destinationTable)
        {
//...
                await destinationTable.ExecuteAsync(insert);
```

Comment: Changing the signature of the function results in the following error for me: The return type of an async method must be void, Task, Task<T>, a task-like type, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, or IAsyncEnumerator<T>... 'Function1.CopyRows(List<RoleAssignment>, CloudTable)': not all code paths return a value

Comment: It is not enough to change the signature of the function, you also need to add `await` at two places.

Comment: Even after adding the awaits at the two places, I still have the function signature error plus this error at the 'await CopyRows' line: ('Task' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of task 'Task' could be found)